# Office 365 API to detect when office app is launched

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to detect when a user launches one of the Office apps (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, OneDrive, etc) so that I can add logic to perform some tasks if it's the first time the user has launched that particular Office app.

I was hoping the Microsoft Graph API would help me with this, but I can't find any guidance on how to do this. Is there a way to do this either with notifications or by polling/querying the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're asking for is **Azure AD Reporting API for Sign-in activity**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference

Note that, at this time, this is only available in the **Azure AD Graph, not the Microsoft Graph**.

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta
```

You can **filter by user and/or appDisplayName**.

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta&$filter=appDisplayName eq 'Office 365'
```

Doing some quick testing by launching the Office Portal, Outlook, Sharepoint, etc, I saw the following entries:

- Office 365
- O365 Suite UX
- Office 365 Exchange Online
- Office.com
- Office 365 SharePoint Online
- Skype Web Experience On Office 365

You'll need to do some experimentation to see if you can see entries for everything your interested in. I don't think you'll get entries down to the granularity level you seem to be interested (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the AD Graph. I've been at a dead-end with this problem up until your answer.